# Send an array in firebase cloud function to the realtime database using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on the cloud functions to create an API that take dictionary of array like this

```
["keyOne":
     ["itemOne","itemTwo"],
  "keyTwo":
     ["itemone","itemTwo"]
]
```

i created the cloud function that take it inside the body and i sent the body using the postman but still i have an issue the dictionary store in the firebase log as a string

cloud function code:

```
exports.createProduct = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'not allowed'
        })
    }
    console.log(req.body.variants)
    var firebaseRef = db.ref("product").push();
    firebaseRef.set({
        variants: req.body.variants
    });
    res.status(200).json({
        message: req.body
    });
});
```

variants as i send :

```
variants:["Key":["items1","items2","items3"]]
```

store in firebase log like this :

```
variants: "[\"Key\":[\"items1\",\"items2\",\"items3\"]]"
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen please check it now

Comment: Can you also share the exact code (postman screenshot of the body tab) used to call the Cloud Function. `variants:["Key":["items1","items2","items3"]]` doesn't look like a valid JSON element: you have a key/value pair as an array element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that last screenshot it looks like you're sending a string, so that is what Firebase stores.

If you want, you can parse the array from the string in your Cloud Functions code:

```
firebaseRef.set({
  variants: JSON.parse(req.body.variants);
})
```

---

It seems you also have a syntax error in your JSON:

```
"[\"Key\":[\"items1\",\"items2\",\"items3\"]]"
```

The closest I can make of it is:

```
"[{\"Key\":[\"items1\",\"items2\",\"items3\"]}]"
```

Or

```
"{\"Key\":[\"items1\",\"items2\",\"items3\"]}"
```

I also highly recommend using single quotes around the string, so you don't have to escape the double quotes inside it:

```
'[{"Key":["items1","items2","items3"]}]'
```

I recommend not creating the JSON by string concatenation, but instead using `JSON.stringify()` to prevent generating invalid JSON.

```
JSON.stringify([{Key: ["items1", "items2", "items3"]}])
```

Which gives:

> `"[{"Key":["items1","items2","items3"]}]"`

Comment: Hi @Frank 

i added your code i got 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 6
    at JSON.parse (
<anonymous>)

Comment: Please provide the textual version of the JSON and code in your question, as I requested in my comment. You might also want to `console.log(req.body.variants)` in your Cloud Function, and include the updated code and its output in your quesetion.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a fairly basic syntax error. Updted my answer to fix that too.